# Is there something similar to KeepAlive property for SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have written a method that navigates through the subfolders of a folder in SharePoint. If the folder has many subfolders to go through, I get this error:

> The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected
>   to be  kept alive was closed by the server..  in
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    in
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()    in
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder
>   sb)

If the folder doesn't have many subfolders in it , the method works fine.So, I was wondering that maybe there is something similar to KeepAlive property for SharePoint that I can use to prevent SharePoint from closing the connection.

**I set the RequestTimeout property of clientContext to infinite, like suggested below, but I still get the error.**

Answer (score 4):

You probably looking for this:

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://server:port/sites/test");
ctx.RequestTimeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
```

Comment: I tried setting the timeout to a very small value:
    ctx.RequestTimeout = 1;

and I get this message now:

The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Comment: This is because you are adding time 1milisecond (1000ms = 1sec) of time, which is not enough to even make connections. For example put 60,000 as a value, then you'll get the error after 1min.

Comment: Also, when we are unsure how much time is required to execute the following script, use Infinite. If this solves your problem please mark the ans as well.

Comment: Hey, I set the timeout to infinite but I get the same error. Do you have any idea why?